# No overload for "MainTimer_Tick" matches delegate "System.EventHandler"

Tags: c#, timer

I've read many questions here already but I do not know how it could help the game-breaking error I have.

In my Mario game I have the form `GameGUI.cs`. I have a timer called `MainTimer`. When I try to run the error

> No overload for "MainTimer_Tick" matches delegate "System.EventHandler"

shows up. I do not know what is going on.

```
//
// MainTimer
//
this.MainTimer.Enabled = true;
this.MainTimer.Interval = 16;
this.MainTimer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.MainTimer_Tick);
```

I have a lot of code for MainTimer_Tick. This is the issue, I think.

```
private void MainTimer_Tick(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
```

Is this the problem?

Comment: The first thing to do after a copy/paste is to be sure that the new code is correct for its intended purpose. A KeyDown/KeyPress event doesn't have the same arguments of a Timer.Tick event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needto have `EventArgs` instead of `KeyEventArgs`

Replace This:

```
private void MainTimer_Tick(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
```

With This:

```
private void MainTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

**EDIT:**

if you want to handle keys on the form (on any control ex:Textbox) you needto handle the `KeyDown` event of that control as below:

```
//set the KeyPreview of the Form to true

this.KeyPreview=true;
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        //code to handle the key down events
}
```

Comment: I tried EventArgs but it has KeyCodes in it and that causes a deadly syntax error.

Comment: then you should handle the `KeyDown` event on the Form, let me update my post.

Comment: Thank you. The bug is fixed and I can now continue coding so that Mario can run!

Comment: @DOODC84: You are welcome :) , glad tobe help of you.